# Getting the first element from my python array

Tags: python, arrays

I encounter some difficulties to print the first element of my python array.

My array is created with :

```
headers = json.loads(entries[0].form_data_headers)
```

(From my views.py).

Then in my template :

(From my template.html)

```
<tr>
              <td>{%for entry in headers%}</td>
              <tr>{{entry}}</tr>

              {% endfor %}                  
              </tr>
```

It prints all the values, i'm okay with that. Even if i try {{entry[0]}} it will screen an error message.

My purpose is to print each entry for each column. And not all of them in one column.

What should i do ?

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `{{headers[0]}}` ?

Comment: {{headers[0]}} doesn't work. But thank for your reply Anthony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is in your html

it should be

```
<tr>
   {% for entry in headers %}
       <td>
           {{ entry }}
       </td>
   {% endfor %}
</tr>
```

this will give you one table row with each entry of header in one column